# Can't override method (Flash Builder) - #1065 Variable Override is not defined

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, overriding

I can't seem to be able to override methods in Flash Builder. I get the following error: #1065 Variable Override is not defined. Worst part is that now it seems Flash Builder got bugged or something because I deleted the line that contained the error and I still get it, I can't even run my project anymore, so I need help with that too. Thanks to anyone in advance for helping.

And for some reason the error states the problem is in line 0:
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Override is not defined.
    at Enemy$cinit()[C:...\src\Enemy.as:0]

This is the code:

```
public class Character extends Sprite
    {

    ...
    protected function moveDown():void
        {
            if ( isAdded == true && isAlive == true)
            {
                if (_loader.y < BOTTOM_HEIGHT)
                    _loader.y += _vel;
                if (_loader.y >= BOTTOM_HEIGHT)
                    _loader.y = BOTTOM_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
}


    public class Enemy extends Character
{
   ...

   protected override function moveDown():void
   {
      //different stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? Looks like it is something else than what you show here. Or did you make a type on `Override`?

Comment: Try project clean. If not try closing / re-opening Builder

Comment: Are you using a game library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, kind of an strange error, but oh well. I had to press the cross icon that says "Remove Launch" and "Remove All Terminated Launches" next to the stop icon in the console tab. I even restarted my PC, tried project>clean, and restarted Flash Builder several times but only that fixed it. I leave this here just in case anyone meets the same error.

Comment: You know you can accept your own answer? It will net you some essential reputation ;).